# How to value display based drop down select value pass one page to other page in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have created 5 drop down using different id here my drop  code looks

i have Two page  this code contain home page. i have another page its called results page.

Home page:

```
 <select name="firsttype" id="firsttype" class="dropdown" onChange="javascript:secondsChanged()">
   <option value="normal">Normal </option>
<option value="silent"> Silent </option>
  </select>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-5 padding-Zero">
 <select name="secondtype" id="secondtype" class="dropdown" onChange="javascript:secondsChanged()">
  <option value="normal">Normal </option>
 <option value="silent"> Silent </option>
       </select>
      </div>

<div class="col-md-5 padding-Zero">
  <select name="thirdtype" id="thirdtype" class="dropdown" onChange="javascript:secondsChanged()">
     <option value="normal">Normal</option>
<option value="silent"> Silent</option>
        </select>
          </div>
```

my results page code  looks like value find

```
    <label id="2nd-Value" class="col-sm-1 padding-Zero">N</label>
    <label id="3rd-Value" class="col-sm-1 padding-Zero">N</label>
    <label id="4th-Value" class="col-sm-1 padding-Zero">N</label>
    <label id="5th-Value" class="col-sm-1 padding-Zero">N</label>
    <label id="5th-Value" class="col-sm-1 padding-Zero">N</label>
```

i have tired using session not getting value

```
<?php
session_Start();
$secondtype = $_POST['secondtype '];
$thirdtype  = $_POST['thirdtype'];
?>
```

Now label value assign N is default. my question when user select  Normal Second Mortgage value is display "N" .
 if user select  1st-time Home Buyer Silent Second value is display S now value is default  N. both are different page ? any idea about it?

Comment: please anyone have idea about it?

Comment: my question different @suvroc

Comment: @suvroc please look my question now

Comment: There are three `<select>` tags with all the same id (`thirdtype`) _and_ name (`thirdtype`). Each form field _should_ have a unique id _and_ name.

Comment: sorry my mistake i edited still not Working

Comment: What have you tried further? Can you show what your form looks like on the Home page and what PHP code you use to create the results page? Without it, we can't see what might go wrong...

Comment: @MartenKoetsier please see my code i have used session

Comment: I don't think that `session_start` has anything to do with this. Please post your entire form-code: does it use `method="post"`? And also show what you do (in PHP) to write those `label` lines. Those pieces of code will provide insight in what you did and what might be improved. Without it, it is absolutely impossible to come to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Notes**
You don't need `session` here , you just move a value from PHP page to another so you should use `$_POST` or `$_GET`
in the example blow i use `$_POST`.

You can also see:

[PHP.net POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

[W3schools $_GET and $_POST](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

**[HTML]: index.html**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
     First Type  :
     <select name="firsttype" id="firsttype">
         <option value="normal">Normal</option>
         <option value="silent">Silent</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      Second Type:
      <select name="secondtype" >
        <option value="normal">Normal</option>
        <option value="silent"> Silent </option>
      </select>
      <br>
      Third Type  :
      <select name="thirdtype">
         <option value="normal">Normal</option>
         <option value="silent">Silent</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="OK!!">
  </form>
```

**[PHP]: page.php**

```
$firsttype  = $_POST["firsttype"]  ==  "normal" ? "N" : "S" ;
$secondtype = $_POST["secondtype"] ==  "normal" ? "N" : "S" ;
$thirdtype  = $_POST["thirdtype"]  ==  "normal" ? "N" : "S" ;
echo "
    <labal name='firsttype'>First Type  :  $firsttype </labal>
    <br>
    <labal name='secondtype'>Second Type:  $secondtype</labal>
    <br>
    <labal name='thirdtype'>Third Type  :  $thirdtype </labal>
";
```

**HTML Result:**

[image: HTML Result]

**PHP Result:**

[image: PHP Result]

Comment: thank  you @Osama Mohamed i will check

Comment: without submit   button its  possible ?

Comment: working ...thank you